# how to serve html file with using router in gin?

Tags: go

I'm practicing using gin framework to make web server and trying to serve 'index.html' file to web browser. so, I searched about how to manage it and wrote code like below but it occures 'http error 500 '. Where I have to amend codes?

main.go

```
    package main

import (
    "comento/works/pkg/router"
    
)



func main(){
    r := router.Router()    
    r.Run(":8081")  
    
}

}
```

router.go

```
package router

import (
    // "comento/works/pkg/api"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    
)

func Router() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Header("Content-Type", "text/html")
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{})
    })

    return r
}
```

and directory status below

works
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── images
├── index
│   └── index.html
├── internal
│   └── global.go
├── main.go
└── pkg
├── api
│   └── image.go
└── router
└── router.go

Answer (score 2):

The following error occurs with your code:

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

You have to tell Gin to load the HTML files first using:

- `func (*gin.Engine).LoadHTMLFiles(files ...string)` or
- `func (*gin.Engine).LoadHTMLGlob(pattern string)`

In your case with your provided directory structure:

```
func Router() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.LoadHTMLFiles("index/index.html") // either individual files like this
    // r.LoadHTMLGlob("index/*")        // or a glob pattern
    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{})
    })
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accorfing to Documents serving static file is as followings:

```
   r.StaticFS("/index.html", http.Dir("<your_directory_name>"))
```

[Documents reference](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/serving-static-files/)